# MongoDB Input Plugin for Logstash: JVM Crashes with Fatal Error

Tags: logstash

I'm using Logstash 8.3.3 on MacOS (Apple Silicon) and created around 60 pipelines in logstash. Logstash starts up fine if I use less than 10 pipelines. Anything greater than 10 results in JVM crashing:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=41063, tid=63747
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.15+10 (11.0.15+10) (build 11.0.15+10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.15+10 (11.0.15+10, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, concurrent mark sweep gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
[thread 64771 also had an error]
[thread 68867 also had an error]
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/hashamrasheed/Work/logstash-8.3.3/bin/hs_err_pid41063.log
[thread 60419 also had an error]
[thread 64259 also had an error]
[thread 59907 also had an error]
[thread 71939 also had an error]
[thread 172547 also had an error][thread 70659 also had an error]

[thread 73475 also had an error]
[thread 174339 also had an error]
[thread 174087 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

At this point, I'm not sure how to debug this issue. I've also increased JVM heap size and stack size to 4g and 10m respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading the SQLite version being used in logstash-input-mongodb plugin. I upgraded it to 3.28.0, everything's working now.